# Reshape 2D tuple to 1D

Tags: python, 2d

I have a tuple (32 x 120):

example  (4x120)

```
[ [1, 2, 3, 4, .... , 118, 119, 120],
  [2, 3, 4, 5, .... , 119, 120, 121],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, .... , 120, 121, 122], 
  [4, 5, 6, 7, .... , 121, 122, 123] ]
```

and I want a vector like this :

```
[1,2,3,4, 2,3,4,5, 3,4,5,6, 4,5,6,7, ..... 118,119,120,121, 119,120,121,122, 120,121,122,123]
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way would be to do this in Numpy as you can simply transpose the array with `T` and then `flatten()` it into a 1D array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ [1, 2, 3, 4  118, 119, 120],
             [2, 3, 4, 5, 119, 120, 121],
             [3, 4, 5, 6, 120, 121, 122], 
             [4, 5, 6, 7, 121, 122, 123] ] )

print(x.T.flatten())
```

gives

```
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   2,   3,   4,   5,   3,   4,   5,   6,   4,
         5,   6,   7, 118, 119, 120, 121, 119, 120, 121, 122, 120, 121,
       122, 123])
```

If you wanted it as a list rather than an array it would be `x.T.flatten().tolist()`

For a non-Numpy solution, you could use this:

```
[inner for outer in zip(*x) for inner in outer]
```

Which returns the same output as above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumPy `np.ravel` to flatten an array.

Example using tuple of tuples (works for lists too):

```
import numpy as np
a = ((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (4,5,6))
np.ravel(a)
```

Gives an array where which is unravelled by appending the rows:

```
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6])
```

This can be done column wise as:

```
np.ravel(a, order='F')
>>> array([1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6])
```

Arrays can be converted to a list easily, eg:

```
np.ravel(a).tolist()
>>> [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```